# asp forms to make post on other page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a form and basically what I'm trying to get it to do is basically take the input boxes and make a "post" or article on another page. So basically this is the page that will create a feed of stories on another page.

I'm pretty sure I'll have to add a form action, but this is what i have and if anyone could at least steer me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

```
<form id="newPost" method="post"><input id="heading" name="Heading" type="text" />
    <div><span contenteditable="true"></span></div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
    <style type="text/css">#heading {
        width:400px; 
    }
    span {
     border: solid 1px black;
    }
    div {
         max-width: 400px;
         max-height:400px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: So you have a page with input to write a post and when you finish you want to click the button and go to another page to add the post and show the feed with the new post added, did I get it right? do you have to use html input or no problem with asp.net button control ?

Comment: yes you've got it right. I'm not very familiar with asp.net so i'd prefer html but i'm open to trying it @Dabbas

Answer (score 0):

No, a form one page won't be able to change the functions or elements on the other page.

You can use a server-side page, to add an `action` attribute to the form. But doing this, in one window and getting the result on the other window ain't gonna happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention any asp page in the action attribute. In the action page you can get request.form("element name").

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ASP.NET controls (ASP.NET TextBox & ASP.NET Button)
**1-** Put a Button inside ASP:Form ..
When clicking on the button the `OnClick` event of it (you should be defined it) will add the post to DB, then if the operation succeeded you can redirect `Response.Redirect` the user to the feed page.
**2-** Buttons in ASP.NET has property called `PostBackUrl`, its value should be the relative path of feed page , let's say '~/Feed.aspx', now when button clicked the postback goes to '~/Feed.aspx' page with the value of `TextBox` in previous page.
All you have is to get the values and insert them in `Page_Load` method like this:
  **A.** Check if post button from previous page clicked:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToLower().Contains("theIDofASP.NETButtonInPreviousPage"))  
{ //your insert code }
```

**B.** Getting the values will besomething similar to this:

```
var indexOfValue = Request.Form.AllKeys.First(k => k.ToLower().EndsWith("theIDofTextBoxOrAnyControlInPreviousPage"));
var theValueYouWant = Request.Form[index];
```

**Note:**
**B** step should be inside if statement in **A** step.

This code will accomplish what you asked for but it's not clean way to do it what you want to do, it's better to stick with pure ASP.NET code.

Comment: Thanks @dabbas I'll have to look into this